# Is log-rank parametric or non-parametric test, and why?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, exponential-distribution, logrank-test

How is the log-rank test a "non-parametric test" according to wikipedia.org if one has to specify the parametric survival model for this test?

We may run log-rank under the assumption of exponential probability distribution, weibull, gamma, log-logistic all of which are parametric models.

Comment: Hi, can you link to a source demonstrating the logrank test being deployed with any of those distributional assumptions (i.e. Weibull), or show us what you mean?

Comment: distribution -> hazard ratio -> log-rank -test

Comment: That's not a link to a source.